# Why the pinging process doesn't stop after playbook is finished?

Tags: iis, ansible

My playbook has to delete all files form the IIS sit folder, replace them with other files and then ping the localhost website. The pinging process doesn't seem to stop after playbook is finished. When I run playbook for the first time everything seems to work fine. But when I try to run it for the second time I get error while deleting files:

> TASK [Delete files from site files ALL]
>   **************************************** fatal: [10.156.5.245]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to delete
>   \file.dll: Access to the path '\file.dll' is
>   denied."}

```
name: Delete files from site files ALL
      win_file:
        path: {{ some path }}
        state: absent
name: Ping the localhost website
      win_uri:
        url: http://localhost:48103/ping
      run_once: true
```

Am I using win_uri wrong or is it some other issue?

After some thinking obout answer to my question I've come up with the idea of restarting the IIS App Pool in which I have my site. It's a workaround and I'm still loking for other answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with admin access using become.

```
- name: Delete files from site files ALL
  win_file:
      path: {{ some path }}
      state: absent
  become: yes
```

Comment: After adding the become I get other error:

```
fatal: [10.156.5.245]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Comment: what is the path you have given. The path should have something like `D:\file.dll`. In the error message it shows `\file.dll:`

Comment: I have the correct path, otherwise the playbook would fail on the first run. I've run out of ideas how to fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

try to use the process monitor to capture the access denied exception.

[download link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

after downloading extract the folder and open the process monitor application.

Process Monitor starts capturing events automatically. Stop capturing by clicking Capture button (CTRL + E) in the toolbar.

[image]

From the Filter menu, and click Filter.

[image]

In the Process Monitor Filter dialog, click the Reset button. This is to clear filters.

Then, set the filtering options as the one below, to catch specifically "Access Denied" entries.

[image]

Click Add, and click OK.

Start capturing by enabling the Capture toggle button in the toolbar.

reproduce the problem and check the process monitor entry.

Comment: I'm working on a Linux VM so I won't be able to download this app... But I'll try to capture the process otherwise. Do you know the way to do so using some Ansible module?

Comment: you could try to use failed request tracing [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). which permission is set to the dll file?